# How to create a bar line chart with the dygraphs package in R?

Tags: r, plot, dynamic, dygraphs, r-dygraphs

I want to create a bar and line chart with the dygraphs package. Like this: [Bar & Line Chart Dygraph](http://dygraphs.com/tests/plotters.html), or again, like this: [Series plotter in this page](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-custom-plotters.html) but I can't find the `dyBarSeries` function.

I managed to plot bar plot with the `rangeselector` with the dygraphs package, by creating the function (the .js is in the package, it was enough to indicate the path to the function) but impossible to find the function for the bar & line chart.

Someone already had the same problem? I really need help, thanks in advance.

Here is the complete code:

Packages I use and functions I create: I wish I could do the same thing for DyBarSeries (or another form of chart) but I can not find the .js

```
library(TTR)
library(stringr)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

dyBarChart <- function(dygraph) { 
  dyPlotter(dygraph = dygraph,
            name = "BarChart",
            path = "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/dygraphs/examples/plotters/barchart.js")
}

dyMultiColumn <- function(dygraph) {
  dyPlotter(dygraph = dygraph,
            name = "MultiColumn",
            path = "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/dygraphs/examples/plotters/multicolumn.js")
}
```

After, I build my file, but it's not interesting here. For the graphic my data is organized like this:

`Sommeil      EMA
2017-11-07      10 0.000000
2017-11-20       5 0.000000
2017-11-25       8 0.000000
2017-11-27      10 0.000000
2017-11-28      10 0.000000
2017-12-01       4 0.000000
2017-12-10       5 7.428571
2017-12-15       6 7.071429
2018-01-08       2 5.803571`

This line works but I end up with a multibarchart :

```
 test <- dygraph(playerF) %>%
  dyRangeSelector() %>% dySeries("EMA", color = rgb((161/255), (94/255), (27/255), 0.80)) %>% dySeries("Sommeil", color = rgb((40/255), (94/255), (27/255), 0.80)) %>% dyMultiColumn() %>% dyUnzoom
test
```

Comment: Please revise your question to include the code you've tried so far.

Comment: According [to the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dygraphs/versions/1.1.1.4), the latest `dygraphs` does not include the `dyBarSeries` function.

Comment: Yes, the `dyBarSerie` function is not included in the package version (with Rdocumentation) but I understand that we could enrich its package with javascripts through the `dyPlotter` function. Yes i post the code now